# WPF rolldown animation

Tags: wpf, animation, controls

I want to create a container in WPF, which will display variable number of items. These items will be attached to the container via a Collection through a DependencyProperty.

I would like to display that container rolled up as long as items are not set. Then, when the items are set, I would like to animate rolling the container down to the size, when all items will be available.

I'm novice in WPF animations, but they seem quite straightforward for me. The thing I don't know is how to specify start and end size of the container without entering precise sizes in pixels. I need to animate from (size without additional controls) to (size with additional controls) and I quite have no idea, where to start.

How can I specify such relative sizes in WPF animation storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using the `ActualHeight` property:

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid Name="Container" ClipToBounds="True">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" ... >
            <ListBox.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListBox.SizeChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Container" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot, 
FallbackValue=0, Mode=OneWay}" Duration="00:00:0.3" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ListBox.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Note that I didn't use the `From` property of the `DoubleAnimation`... this will enable the animation to 'grow' as each item is added.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have to investigate this solution. In my case, it is a matter of Content being shown or not. The control is being displayed without content and when that content is being attached, control should roll down to display it.